# Is this pirate in the background a young Edward Teague?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-men-tell-no-tales

I just watched the fifth Pirates of The Caribbean movie, Dead Men Tell No Tales, and noticed a potentially familiar figure during one of the flashbacks. Specifically, during a flashback to when Jack Sparrow became a Captain for the first time, the movie showed a pirate standing behind him as he surveyed his crew and his tribute:

[image]

I couldn't help but think this man in the background looks similar to, and is dressed similarly to Jack's dad, Edward Teague, from the third movie, At World's End:

[image]

Is this just a doppelganger, or is that really Jack Sparrow's father behind him in the flashback?

Comment: that's just a PA who accidentally stepped in the shot ;)

Comment: Shouldn't Teague should be much older than Jack? in this he looks like he's in same age group as Jack

Comment: By the way, the picture quality is pretty good.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, he is Edward Teague and looks like he didn't change his coat since then. **Filthy Pirate!**

> Teague, Jack, and the surviving crew members watched the end of El Matador Del Mar. Teague was standing on the forecastle behind Jack when several crew members offered Jack a tribute. Teague looked from behind his son as he was crowned with his new belongings

**[Wikia](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Edward_Teague)**

According to [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1790809/fullcredits), [Alexander Scheer](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0770449/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm) was cast as Young Teague.

After movie credits snapshot.

[image: from credits.]

Comment: while the wiki states it as such, there's no citation anywhere that proves that it is actually intended to be Teague

Comment: @DForck42: Do you mean Wikia is not a reliable source ?

Comment: kinda, yeah.  imdb listing Young Teague as a character definitely helps

Comment: They have photos of him at the film's premiere also, but don't discloss whom he plays there: http://www.zimbio.com/photos/Alexander+Scheer/Premiere+Disney+andnd+Jerry+Bruckheimer+Films/o2qheh-00Pv

Comment: @Rahul Without citation, Wikia (and even Wikipedia) sometimes can't be reliable sources.

Comment: Shouldn't Teague should be much older than Jack? in this he looks like he's in same age group as Jack

Comment: @Vishwa he looks 35-40 for me. enough old to have "made" jack at 16-18-20 age. look at the chin lines and the eyebrows.

Comment: @Vishwa The age of the actors fits, Sheer was born in 1974, de la Torre in 1993.